# Adding onto float within json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I have a JSON object that is dynamically creates based on lots. I'm trying to get the total cost of each lot. Each object in the list is a different purchase.

```
var lot_list = [{lot:123456,cost:'$4,500.00'}, {lot:654321, cost:'$1,600.00'}, {lot:123456, cost:'$6,500.00'}]
```

I want the total cost for each lot so I tried

```
var totalBalances = {};
function addBalance(){
    lot_list.forEach(function(lots){
        totalBalances[lots[lot]] += parseFloat(lots['cost'].replace('$','').replace(',',''));
    });
}
```

This ends with every lot having a null cost
I also tried

```
var totalBalances = {};
function addBalance(){
    lot_list.forEach(function(lots){
        totalBalances[lots[lot]] = parseInt(totalBalances[lots[lot]]) + parseFloat(lots['cost'].replace('$','').replace(',',''));
    });
}
```

Neither of these worked any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `totalBalances[lots[lot]] +=` but no such property exists initially, you want `=`, not `+=`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I thought initially it would just return null and add the key so wouldn't it still add. Also I'm not sure how to fix  since the list needs to be dynamic. Any ideas?

Comment: Accessing a non-existent property gives `undefined`, not null. You can't `+=` to `undefined`. Like I said, use `=` instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance If I use ```=``` it will overwrite the last time the cost was updated.

Comment: @CertainPerformance If you had actually read my question you would be able to see that there can be multiple purchases under that same lot which is way I want the total cost of a lot because sometimes there is close to a hundred purchases of the same lot. So asserting the value would cause the last cost to be overwritten. Could you please un-downvote my question now?

Comment: If you want to add up values into an object and the property doesn't exist on the object initially, then just check that the property exists on the object first, then carry out the appropriate logic. I didn't downvote https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb4Xi.png see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a value to sum with `parseFloat('$4,500.00')` because of the invalid characters. To remove the dollar sign and commas you can replace using;

```
> '$4,500.00'.replace(/[^\d\./g,'')
> "4500.00"
```

Here the regex matches anything that is not a digit or decimal place with the global modifier to replace all occurrances.

You can map your array of objects to the float values using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get an array of float values.

```
> lot_list.map((l) => parseFloat(l.cost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,''))) 
> [4500, 1600, 6500]
```

With an array of float values you can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the sum;

```
> lot_list.map((l) => parseFloat(l.cost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,''))).reduce((a,c) => a+c)
> 12600
```

**EDIT**

To get totals for each lot map an object with the lot id included and then reduce onto an object with;

```
> lot_list
    .map((l) => { 
      return { 
        id: l.lot, 
        cost: parseFloat(l.cost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,'')) 
      }
    })
    .reduce((a,c) => { 
      a[c.id] = a[c.id] || 0; 
      a[c.id] += c.cost; 
      return a; 
    }, {})
> { 123456: 11000, 654321: 1600 }
```

Here the reduce function creates an object as the accumulator and then initialises the sum to zero if the lot id has not been summed before.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code

```
  var totalBalances = {};
  function addBalance(){
    lot_list.forEach(function(lots){
      // totalBalances[123456] is not defined yet, this should gets you problem if you're trying calculate its value 
      // totalBalances[lots[lot]] += parseFloat(lots['cost'].replace('$','').replace(',','')); 

      // maybe you should use this instead
      totalBalances[lots[lot]] = parseFloat(lots['cost'].replace('$','').replace(',','')); 
    });
  }
```

but, if you want to count total value of cost, you might considering using array reduce

```
  function countCost(){
    return lot_list.reduce((accum, dt) => {
      return accum +  parseFloat(l.cost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,''))
    }, parseFloat(0));
  } //this gonna bring you total count of all cost
```